# How to decrease size of smart object in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, smartobject

I downloaded a website showcase mockup, which uses smart objects for the screen layers of a monitor and a smartphone to make it easier to place designs. I need to decrease the size of the smartphone screen layer but am finding that when I do this and then paste a website design, a blank border around the image is added in the final mockup instead of the image being stretched to cover the whole layer.

I don't have much experience in using smart objects, so any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The thing is you can't change the smart object size. What you should do is paste your screenshot inside the smart object and if it's too small or too big, you stretch the screenshot layer to fit the SO document using Free Transform.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could stretch the pasted image outside the smart object edit screen. Thanks!

Comment: You can definitely change the size of smart objects. Just right-click and select transform object.

Comment: Slight mistake - it's "free transform," not "transform object".

Comment: @13ruce, I should've said that slightly differently. OP understood me, but I should've said something like: he **can't touch** the SO size **in this case** or the mockup gets ruined, like what happened with his original attempt. — The description was hard for me to understand, but the result told me  that's what he  did.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. Well, you can also double-click on the smart object to open it directly in its native platform (Illustrator or Photoshop, depending). Once opened, you can alter the object and save it and it will be updated in the source Photoshop document. This /could/ allow you to resize elements without a problem, so long as the outer dimensions don't change. It doesn't always work perfectly, but it's something worth trying.